# Using "$count" Within an "addField" Operation in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, count

I am trying to find the correct combination of aggregation operators to add a field titled "totalCount" to my mongoDB view.

This will get me the count at this particular stage of the aggregation pipeline and output this as the result of a count on each of the documents:

```
    {
        $count: "count"
    }
```

But I then end up with one document with this result, rather than what I'm trying to accomplish, which is to make this value print out as an `addedField` that is a field/value on all of the documents, or even better, a value that prints `in addition` to the returned documents.

I've tried this but it gives me an error ""Unrecognized expression '$count'",":

```
    {
        $addFields: {
          "totalCount" : { $count: "totalCount" }
        }
    }
```

What would the correct syntactical construction be for this? Is it possible to do it this way, or do I need to use `$sum`, or some other operator to make this work? I also tried this:

```
    {
        $addFields: {
          "totalCount" : { $sum: { _id: 1 } }
        }
    },
```

... but while it doesn't give me any errors, it just prints `0` as the value for that field on every document rather than the total count of all documents.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Total count will always be a one-document result so you need [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) to run mutliple aggregation pipelines and then merge results. Let's say your regular pipeline contains simple `$project` and you want to merge it's results with `$count`. You can run below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            totalCount: [
                { $count: "value" }
            ],
            pipelineResults: [
                {
                    $project: { _id: 1 } // your regular aggregation pipeline here 
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$pipelineResults"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$totalCount"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ "$pipelineResults", { totalCount: "$totalCount.value" } ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

After `$facet` stage you'll get single document like this

```
{
    "totalCount" : [
        {
            "value" : 3
        }
    ],
    "pipelineResults" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b313241120e4bc08ce87e46")
        },
        //....
    ]
}
```

Then you have to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to transform arrays into multiple documents and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to promote regular pipeline results into root level.

Comment: @micki, for some reason I'm getting an error on the $mergeObjects step?

The following error occurred while attempting to execute the aggregate query

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 168: 'Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'' on server mrbbetaconfig1.blsa.com:27017. Any ideas?

Comment: @Muirik probably because you have MongoDB lower than 3.6. You can achieve the same result with `$project` if you can't upgrade

Comment: Right. I'm running 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Since mongoDB version 5.0 there is another option, that allows to avoid the disadvantage of $facet, the grouping of all returned document into a one big document. The main concern is that a document as a size limit of 16M. Using $setWindowFields allows to avoid this concern

This can simply replace @micki's 4 steps:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$setWindowFields: {output: {totalCount: {$count: {}}}}}
])
```

Comment: This seems to add a totalCount field to each item. How would you do this to get the totalcount as a separate field? Or would using $facet in that case be better?

Comment: It is adding a `totalCount` field to each item. This a way to avoid grouping all documents together (using `$group` or '$facet`) which result in one large document.

Comment: Thanks, I used grouping indeed and pushed the root to results. 
` '$group' => [ '_id' => null, 'total' => ['$sum' => 1], 'results' => ['$push' => '$$ROOT']]`