# How to count resulting grouped objects in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, pagination, aggregation

In a smart way.
Simple pagination task. I have 1000 objects, wanna group them and send to API 10 at a time.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$name",
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "surnames": {
                "$addToSet": "$surname"
            },
            "objects": {
                "$push": "$$ROOT"
            },
        }
    },
    {$limit:10},
    {$skip:300}
],  { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

This will give me 10 objects, starting from 300th. Cool. 
How do I get the total number of grouped objects?

**[$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)** stage will not allow me to keep my grouped results

Doing this trick:

```
{$group: {_id: null, $totalCount:{$sum:1}, $results: { "$push": "$$ROOT"}}
```

and then ungrouping it will ruin my limits and looks not very smart.

And, of course, doing another aggregation with $count as last stage and without limits is not an option. Because of speed.

I will be happy for any advice.

Comment: You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029987/using-count-within-an-addfield-operation-in-mongodb-aggregation/51030473#51030473

Comment: Thanks mickl! $Fracet can be exactly what I want. I will test that in next few days and leave the comment than.

Comment: You can run your `$group` first and then `$facet` with count

Comment: Yes, that's the plan

Comment: Jepp, it's working. @mickl can create an answer based on your comment (look here: ...) so I can star it is "good answer"?

Answer (score 0):

First I think you need to switch the position of your `$limit` and `$skip` stages.

Because your grouping by `name` you could use Mongo's [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) on that field and check the `length` of the array, like so:

```
let names = await db.collection.distinct("name");
let totalLength = names.length - 300;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Tom! Can you provide more info about the part where you suggest to switch position of $limit and $skip stages? About 'distinct' - that's my fault for oversimplifying the task. I group by a number of fields, pass the results through several layers of projection and so on - in short, I can't just index name and run it through distinct. Sadly -(