# MongoDB Aggregate - Get Total Count and Skip in one pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get the total count of documents which match my pipeline operators and then after I get that count of all of them I would like to use `$skip` and `$limit` to return a subset for pagination. Right now I am basically doing the same aggregation twice - once to get the count of all matches and once to do the skip/limit. **Can this be done using one aggregation pipeline?**

To get the count I do

```js
let [count] = await MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      store: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storeId),
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "resaleitems",
      let: {
        store: "$store",
      },
      as: "itemsForSale",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$store", "$$store"],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "itemsForSale.0": { $exists: true },
    },
  },
  { $count: "totalCount" },
]).exec();
```

and then right after to get the skipped and limited results I do basically the same thing, but have added the $skip and $limit steps

```js
let items = await MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      store: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storeId),
    },
  },
  { $skip: skip.toNumber() },
  { $limit: bnLimit.toNumber() },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "resaleitems",
      let: {
        store: "$store",
      },
      as: "itemsForSale",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$store", "$$store"],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "itemsForSale.0": { $exists: true },
    },
  },
]).exec();
```

Comment: You can try using `$facet` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029987/using-count-within-an-addfield-operation-in-mongodb-aggregation/51030473#51030473

Comment: Thanks @mickl that works.