# How to count number of root documents in intermediate aggregate stage in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pagination, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to implement pagination on a website and I'd like my mongodb query to return first perform the lookup between 2 collections, sort the documents, calculate the total number of documents and then return the relevant documents after `$skip` and `$limit` stages in the aggregation. This is my query:

```
const res = await Product.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Brand',
      localField: 'a',
      foreignField: 'b',
      as: 'brand'
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      c: 1,
      'brand.d': -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: offset
  },
  {
    $limit: productsPerPage
  }
])
```

I don't want to make 2 queries which are essentially the same only for the first one to return the count of documents and for the other to return the documents themselves.

So the result would be something like this:

```
{
  documents: [...],
  totalMatchedDocumentsCount: x
}
```

such that there will be for example 10 `documents` but `totalMatchedDocumentsCount` may be `500`.

I can't figure out how to do this, I don't see that `aggregate` method returns cursor. Is it possible to achieve what I want in one query?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029987/using-count-within-an-addfield-operation-in-mongodb-aggregation/51030473#51030473 ?

Comment: @mickl thank you, in a way it does but in the solution you referenced I will have the count in each document which is not very efficient because I need the count only once on the root level of the document. I guess I need to group the documents and then add a field of total count and delete total count per each document but again this seems extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) and you can run your pipeline with `$limit` and `$skip` as one subpipeline while `$count` can be used simultaneously:

```
const res = await Product.aggregate([
    // $match here if needed
    {
        $facet: {
            documents: [
                {
                    $lookup: {
                    from: 'Brand',
                    localField: 'a',
                    foreignField: 'b',
                    as: 'brand'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                    c: 1,
                    'brand.d': -1
                    }
                },
                {
                    $skip: offset
                },
                {
                    $limit: productsPerPage
                }
            ],
            total: [
                { $count: "count" }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$total"
    }
])
```