# MongoDb Aggregation - How to get $count along with other properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

[MobgoDb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Kzg9qmtIDH)

**Attempt 1:** (this returned only the total )

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "dob.age": 59
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "total"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "dob.age": 1,
      "total":1
    }
  }
])
```

**Attempt 2** (Exception -A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "dob.age": 59
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "total",
    "dob.age": 1
  } 
])
```

**Attempt 3 (empty object):**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "dob.age": 59
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "dob.age": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029987/using-count-within-an-addfield-operation-in-mongodb-aggregation/51030473#51030473 ?

Comment: @mickl Do we really need that many steps? I come from RDBS background and in RDBMS this would have been extremely simple.

Comment: @SamuraiJack you just need one pipeline `$facet` look this https://mongoplayground.net/p/wG4qtu-Mty3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this - [have equivalent to $count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/#behavior)

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5WwNrknUWE7)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { //match condition
      "dob.age": 59
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {//$count equivalent
      _id: null,
      myCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "data": {//all other fields
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {//removing null id - you can skip this if null id is not a problem
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: 1) What's $$ROOT? 
2) If I only want a single property along with Total, wouldnt this be bad for performance since I will be passing all of the unwanted properties in the pipeline?

Comment: You can do that. Look for `$first, $addToSet, $last, $push `and many more from the documentation. At high level it would be, `"fieldOne": { $push: "$fieldOne"}` Each operator has it's own value. You can use in place fo `$push`

Answer (score 0):

If you run `match:"dob.age": 59` the output age will be a constant 59.

In any case, you need to run the group by so you will have the total of rows by age:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "dob.age": 59
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$dob.age",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      age: "$_id",
      "total": 1
    }
  }
])
```

otherwise I would suggest to run simply:

```
db.collection.count({"dob.age": 59}) // it will be 2 as well
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention that you want to count on cloud.mongodb.com (cloud mongo), I would like to add that part also.
In cloud mongo you add the following query to get the count:

Stage 1: **$match:**

```
    /**
     * Query: The query in MQL.
     */
    {
      "YOUR_KEY":"YOUR_VALUE_FOR_FETCH"
    }
```

Stage 2: **$count:**

```
/**
 * Provide the field name for the count.
 */
'total'
```

**Example:**

screenshot of cloud mongo:

[image]